# PHP - imagecolorat() to rgb or hex?

Tags: php, css, indexing, hex, rgb

I use this code:

```
for($x=0;$x<$stageWidth;$x++){
    $stageColors[$x] = [];
    for($y=0;$y<$stageHeight;$y++){
        array_push($stageColors[$x],imagecolorat($pngImage,$x,$y));
    }
}
```

To store all the color indexies in a array.

But how can I echo them out as something CSS compatible?

for example:

```
<div style="background:#<?php echo $either_RGBA_OR_HEX; ?>" ></div>
```

Does not really matter if RGBA (or RGB), or HEX

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php#115609

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a help to get rgb values :

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("php.png");
$rgb = imagecolorat($im, 10, 15);
$r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b = $rgb & 0xFF;

var_dump($r, $g, $b);//shows the individual values that you can use
?>
```

Comment: See [http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php)